# Law (Probability)

Tags: probability

I am trying to read a paper. I need help understanding the following:
If $\mu$ is a probability measure, then what does Law($\mu$) mean?

Here is an extract from the passage:

"Let (X,µ) and (Y,ν) be two probability spaces. Coupling µ and ν means constructing two random variables X and Y on some probability space (Ω,P), such that law(X) = µ, law(Y ) = ν".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete Nicholas' answer, if $Z:(\Omega,P)\rightarrow X$ is a random variable (I denote it by $Z$ since $X$ is also the underlying space), then you define its law to be the measure
$$
P_Z:B\mapsto P_Z(B):=P(Z^{-1}(B)),
$$
for $B$ measurable sets of $X$. Thus $\mathrm{law}(Z)=\mu$ means that the two measures $P_Z$ and $\mu$ coincide.

Answer (score 1):

The 'law' of a random variable is just the variable's associated probability measure.

Note that you weren't asked for $\text{law}(\mu)$, but rather $\text{law}(X)$ where $X$ is a random variable.  If $X$ is a random variable with associated measure $\mu$, then $\mu=\text{law}(X)$.